# Как склоняется фамилия

Tags: фамилии

Склоняется ли фамилия Абдула́ в украинском языке?(ударение падает на последнюю букву а)

Comment: Данный вопрос закрыт, потому что не по теме. Это сообщество русского языка, а не украинского